# Does Blitzcrank's ultimate silence or stop channeling spells?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have seen this phenomenon not only once that when Blitzcrank runs into a TF, he silences for a short duration, stopping channeling for example.

Is this true, or only an assumption on my part?

Comment: Because of the silence you will stop people from channeling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blitzcranks Ultimate is a Silence, however it's duration is only 0.5 Seconds which is why it's usually used as an Interrupt (or for damage) rather than as a silence effect that prevents casting new spells.

The fact that it's AOE and instant makes it a great counter to spells like Katarina Ultimate or Teleport and the main reason why it's a silence is because before the Kassadin rework there was no specific spell effect for Channel interrupts. The only thing that existed back then were hard CC or small knockups/knockbacks.